# Playing a user created sound at a specific time in iOS 7

Tags: audio, ios7, background

What I'm trying to do is set an alarm for a specific time (user picks the time) and play a sound that the user actually creates.  If the app is in the background, the sound still plays.

UILocalnotification - It will only play audio if the file is in the app bundle.  **Is there a way to take a user created audio file, and add to the app bundle?**

Push Notification - Same problem as UILocalnotification - the audio file is NOT in the app bundle.

Schedule a timer in the background - It appears this only works if the alarm is in the next 10 minutes.  **Is there a way to schedule an alert for some time in the future, that is not a UILocal or Push?**

Any other ideas on how this might get accomplished.